Query to parse JSON using openrowset converting special characters
We are trying to process a JSON document using SQL Server 2019. When using the below query to parse JSON document with openrowset its converting special characters. For instance (Ó or Ñ) are converted to Ã‘.
Query:
SELECT d.*
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\drive\data.json', SINGLE_CLOB) X
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (X.BulkColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8, '$.Data')
WITH ([N] NVARCHAR(250) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) AS d

What other options are available to address this issue?

Try SINGLE_BLOB instead

SINGLE_BLOB throws this error JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '੻' is found at position 0.

what about SINGLE_NCLOB?

Unable to parse the file. SINGLE_NCLOB requires a UNICODE (widechar) input file. The file specified is not Unicode.

Are you sure? it seems to have a BOM of some sort?

The '੻' character in your earlier comment is hex 7B 0A, which are single-byte characters for "{" and newline. So, the SINGLE_CLOB option is correct. What you likely need to add is the CODEPAGE = 'nnn' option with the appropriate code page number matching your locale (or whatever the encoding or the original file is). If you open the original file in Notepad++, which "encoding > character sets > region > value" menu option gives you the proper display?

File encoding is utf-8

You can get the JSON as varbinary(max) then cast to varchar(max) with a UTF8 collation. The problem is that the cast automatically takes the database default collation. So you need to hack it with CONCAT.
Note that the collation of the output columns of OPENJSON is the same as the input JSON.
SELECT j.*
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\drive\data.json', SINGLE_BLOB) o
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (
    CONCAT('' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8, o.BulkColumn)
    '$.Data')
  WITH (
    N NVARCHAR(250)
  ) AS j;

